# recalculating the number of subdivisions of a cylinders

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm modeling car wheels and i just spent a bunch of time getting the curvature just right, but now that I'm about to make the rims I'm realizing giving the initial cylinder 32 subdivisions was a mistake and that I should have made it 30 instead to split evenly with 5 and 6 point rims. Is there any way to change the subdivisions to 30 while keeping it a perfect circle?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select one of the cross sections and separate it into a new object or inverse the selection and delete the rest of the object.

[image: Wheel with one cross section selected]

2. Use the Screw modifier to recreate your wheel with Steps set to 30. You might need to change the Axis depending on how your wheel is oriented. Also  check the Merge Vertices checkbox.

[image: New wheel with Screw modifier]

3. Click the Apply button to convert the wheel back to an editable mesh.